# bash autocomplete personal command : cannot autocomplete the argument after the option

Tags: bash, auto-completion

I wrote the autocomplete function for my command, but it is not autocomplete the argument after the option flag

```
function _qpdm_complete() 
{
    local cur prev options my_list
    COMPREPLY=()

    cur="${COMP_WORD[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORD[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    options="-opt" 
    my_list="quantum alpha betta omega operation"   

    if [[ ${cur} == -* || ${COMP_CWORD} -eq 1 ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${options}" ${cur}) )
        return 0
    else 
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${my_list}" -- ${cur}) )
    fi
}

complete -F _qpdm_complete qpdm
```

then in terminal

qpdm

```
qpdm -opt
```

qpdm -opt<TAB>

```
qpdm -opt  
quantum alpha betta omega operation
```

qpdm -opt o<TAB>

expecting

```
qpdm -opt o
omega operation
```

but get

```
qpdm -opt o  
quantum alpha betta omega operation
```

What is missed in my _qpdm_complete()?